# Mimic Matplotlib's "Zoom-to-Rectange" Function

Tags: looker-studio

Is Data Studio able to mimic Matplotlib's "Zoom-to-Rectange" Function? For example, in Matplotlib I can plot the following data:

[image]

Using the "Zoom-to-Rectange" feature I can zoom in on the chosen range to get the following:

[image]

Is this possible in Data Studio?

Comment: Not in the same way. You could probably do something similar using filters would it wouldn't be as user friendly or have quite the same functionality

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use the Community Visualization feature (currently in whitelist-only), you'd be able to implement that functionality yourself using something like d3.js.

[Link to the feature documentation.](http://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization)